# Incrementing string by integer in ruby

Tags: ruby

Suppose the character string is `"abc"` and user input is 3 then the output becomes `"def"`.

Every character is supposed to be increased by the user input as integer value.

I wrote a code but it is giving an error. Is there any other way to do this?

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

puts "Enter the value of n";
$n=gets;
s = String.new("abc");
s.split("").each do |i|
    $j = 0;
    x = i;
    begin
         x.next;
         $j = $j + 1;
    end while $j < $n

    puts x;
end
```

Comment: Should `<<` be `<`?

Comment: yes @SebastianPalma i just edited.

Comment: @SebastianPalma i also tried ( i.ord + n).chr  to directly convert a to d avoiding x.next but this is also giving error - in `+': String can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)

Comment: See ganesh's answer. Try parsing the user's input to integer `$n=gets.to_i`. See the [repl](https://repl.it/@vnhnhm/VictoriousQueasyGoose).

Comment: Have you considered the desired output for the strings whose +n characters fall off the alphabet e.g. `'xyz'` etc?

Comment: Can the string contain capital letters, spaces or punctuation? That should be specified in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several things to add in your code:

- Instead `String.new`, you can simply add your string within quotes.
- `str.split("")` can be `str.chars`.
- `$j = $j + 1` can be `$j += 1`.
- If you're doing a comparison between `$j` and `$n` then `<<` should be `<`.
- You don't need `;` unless you're writing all in one line.
- `begin; end while` can be just `while; end`

I guess it could be like:

```
n = gets.to_i
s = 'abc'
s.split('').each do |i|
  j = 0
  x = i
  while j < n
    x = x.next
    j += 1
  end
  puts x
end
```

But you could use [`String#ord`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-ord) over each char in your string to return the ordinal of it, add the user input and then [`String#chr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-chr) to get the ASCII character for that number:

```
# With n being the user's input as integer, in this case 3.
p 'abc'.chars.map { |char| (char.ord + n).chr }.join 
# "def"
```

Added `n = gets.to_i` as stated in the comments by @Ganesh.

If looking for a Caesar Cipher implementation:

```
def foo(string, n)
  lower = ('a'..'z').to_a.join
  upper = ('A'..'Z').to_a.join
  string.tr(lower + upper, lower[n..-1] + lower[0...n] + upper[n..-1] + upper[0...n])
end

p foo('XYZ', 1) # "YZA"
p foo('ABC', 1) # "BCD"
p foo('ABC', 3) # "DEF"
```

Slower, but...

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Actually one error is disturbing:in `<': comparison of Fixnum with String failed (ArgumentError) . This is happening whenever i am scanning the value of n.. ie by  n=gets

Comment: It's strange, since `j` and `n` are always numbers, what's the code you're trying with?

Comment: I used the same code u have suggested this time: but j and n aren't been compared. in `<': comparison of Fixnum with String failed (ArgumentError) this error is encountered.

Comment: See the working code [here](https://repl.it/@vnhnhm/VictoriousQueasyGoose), is yours implemented the same way?

Comment: instead of `$n=gets;` use `$n=gets.to_i;`

Comment: @SebastianPalma your code is working right, the problem was about gets.

Comment: @GaneshNavale thanks for your suggestions, now working fine.

Comment: Thanks @SebastianPalma for your answer.

Comment: What does this return if you have ‘xyz’ and n = 1?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `tr` and `rotate`. Assumes you want a circular-mapping i.e. `'z' => 'a'` for a +1 map.

```
def caesar str, n
  str.tr 'a-z', [*'a'..'z'].rotate(n).join
end

caesar 'abc', 3 #=> 'def'
caesar 'xyz', 3 #=> 'abc'
```

See [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0) for info on these methods.

Comment: Have just noticed this answer is almost identical to one in a comment by [Stefan to another q&a](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26340710/5101493).

Answer (score 2):

If all characters are lower-case ASCII letters:

```
def caesar(str, n)
  base = 'a'.ord
  str.gsub(/./) { |c| (base + (c.ord+n-base) % 26).chr }
end

str = "abcxyza"
caesar(str,  1) #=> "bcdyzab"
caesar(str,  2) #=> "cdezabc"
caesar(str, 25) #=> "zabwxyz"
caesar(str, 26) #=> "abcxyza"
```

If all characters are ASCII letters:

```
def caesar(str, n)
  str.gsub(/./) do |c|
    base = (c==c.upcase ? 'A' : 'a').ord
    (base + (c.ord+n-base) % 26).chr
  end
end

str = "AbcDefXyZa"
caesar(str,  1) #=> "BcdEfgYzAb"
caesar(str,  2) #=> "CdeFghZaBc"
caesar(str, 25) #=> "ZabCdeWxYz"
caesar(str, 26) #=> "AbcDefXyZa"
```